# How to accept only numbers and a plus (+) sign in a regular expression c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I currently have the regular expression

```html
"^[0-9]{11,12}$"
```

that accepts 11 to 12 numeric digits. I want to modify that expression to accept a plus sign (+)
How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean a standalone `+`? Like `@"^(?:\+|[0-9]{11,12})$"`? Or an optional `+`, like in `@"^\+?[0-9]{11,12}$"`?

Comment: Where abouts in the string do you want to allow `+`?

Comment: if you mean, for example, "+11", you can add just `\+`  at the beginning

Comment: Any number of plus signs, or must it occur in a certain position?

Comment: It should be 1 plus sign at the beginning. and it should be zero or more occurences

Comment: in which place you need a +

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want the optional plus but I want the + to be counted in the 12 digits.

Comment: Not a big issue, `^(?=.{11,12}$)\+?[0-9]+$`